# Mongoose call update without updating 'updatedAt' filed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to increment some value in my DB (mongoose), and I don't want to change the `updatedAt` field for these kind of operations.

My code

```
Post.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$inc: {likes: 1}}).exec();
```

Any idea on how to achieve such operation.

Comment: Are you using **timestamps** option is the mongoose schema?

Comment: Yes I am @cheekujha

Comment: I don't think its possible. Can you tell what is use case, basically if the instance prop is changing updatedAt is going to change

Comment: As you can see I am changing the number of likes of a post, which doesn't mean the post itself is updated, thus I would like to keep `updatedAt` field unchanged. @cheekujha